# Magento 2 : How to locate language packs

Tags: magento2, language, language-package

I try translate other website. I install language pack via composer. Language pack `pl_PL` I found in vendor.
But I research are others folders and I cannot find other languages. eg. `cs_CZ`. Any one know how I can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no official page documenting all language packs, but there is a good compilation of language packs available at Mageplaza (for free, ofcourse) here -
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-language-pack/

These can be installed using composer or manually as per your requirements.